# How much bandwith does a Minecraft server use?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much bandwidth does a Minecraft client use in SMP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22154/how-much-bandwidth-does-a-minecraft-client-use-in-smp)

How much bandwidth does the average (20-40 person server with an average of 30 people playing) Minecraft server use per month? How much bandwidth is used per player?

Comment: Define 'average'.

Comment: Average as in a 20-40 person server with usually 30 people on